# NullPointerException thrown from EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, jpa, nullpointerexception, entitymanager

I have a problem with an `EntityManager`, it throws a `NullPointerException`.
This is the code:

#### PersonServiceJpa.java

```
package com.smartpump.service.jpa;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.smartpump.persistent.entity.Person;
import com.smartpump.service.PersonService;

import java.util.List;

import javax.jdo.annotations.Transactional;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@Service("personService")
public class PersonServiceJpa implements PersonService {
    
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNombre() {
        return "Roberto";
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public List<Person> getAll() {
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Person.findAll");  <--Here is the problem
        List<Person> persons = null;
        persons = query.getResultList();
        return persons;
    }
}
```

The code **`Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Person.findAll");`** is where the `NullPointerException` appears, in the `entityManager` sentence.

Here are other parts of code.

#### persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
        <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
      <!--   <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency" value="EVENTUAL" /> 
        </properties> -->
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

<!-- 
transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
         <class>com.persistent.entity.Person</class>
          -->
```

#### applicationContext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">
            
    <bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>\WEB-INF\database.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driver}" p:url="${jdbc.url}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
    
    <bean id="personService"
        class="com.smartpump.service.jpa.PersonServiceJpa"></bean>
    
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        lazy-init="true">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="transactions-optional" />
    </bean>
    <bean name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException is occurring because of entityManager object is not injected in the PersonServiceJPA class.

In **applicationContext.xml** you are creating the **personService** bean. While creating PersonService bean you need inject the entityManager class.

**Your Code:**

```
<bean id="personService"
        class="com.smartpump.service.jpa.PersonServiceJpa"></bean>
```

**Modified Code:**

```
<bean id="personService"
        class="com.smartpump.service.jpa.PersonServiceJpa">
    <property name="entityManager" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: That is not the correct answer I am afraid. Notice '@PersistenceContext' on the EntityManager. The OP knows it has to be injected, but he wants to do it differently, but it did not work :)

Comment: I try this but I get another error: "Problem accessing /rest/myresource/todos. Reason: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE"

Answer (score 0):

I think that you either have to set:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

in your applicationContext.xml, or alternatively define a special Spring bean (also in applicationContext.xml):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

Please, let me know if it had helped.

Comment: I apply this but doesn't work.
I'm getting the NPE in the same sentence

Comment: Can you upload your some to github or bitbucket? It would be so much easier.

Comment: I added the link of github, but no one answer

Comment: Yeah, well people have a life outside of SO too :) I will try to look into it later on today.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should modify your application-context, to add the transaction annotation config.

```html
<beans xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd"> 
 <context:annotation-config/>
```

2. You should autowire the EntityManager like so :

   @Autowired

   private EntityManager entityManager;

Answer (score 0):

Try to use @PersistenceContext on EntityManager itself,

```
@PersistenceContext
Private EntityManager entityManager;
```

I am not that it works on setter method